# Rails = Help with form_for to pass in two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have two models with a has_one belongs_to releationship called purchase_request (has_one) and purchase_order(belongs_to).  I need to make sure the purchase_request_id gets passed to purchase_order and it has a restufl route that reads:

> > /purchase_requests/:purchase_request_id/purchase_orders/new

and my controller's new method looks like this:

```
def new
 @purchase_request = PurchaseRequest.find_by_id(params[:purchase_request_id])
 @purchase_request.purchase_order = PurchaseOrder.new
end
```

with the view having this:

```
form_for (@purchase_order, @purchase_request) do |f|
```

and I have heard that a hidden field isn't necissary if you do that, but it gives :purchase_request nil in my table.  I also can't figure out how to put the @purchase_request.id into a hidden field.  Help is greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
I would solve it using this code `<%= f.hidden_field :purchase_request_id, :value=>@purchase_request.id %>` however, that would make it so I would have to modify the edit method too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly the right way to do it but I:

- Changed my controller code to:

  ```
  @purchase_order = PurchaseOrder.new({:purchase_request_id=>params[:purchase_request_id]})
  ```
- Made sure my view had:

  ```
  <%= f.hidden_field :purchase_request_id %>
  ```
- and just had:

  ```
  form_for(@purchase_order) do |f|
  ```